A novel about people living hanging on the walls of huge building, with "angels" (?) floating around
I read this novel about 30 years ago, in a rather slim paperback, in French, almost certainly a translation from English. A rather short novel, but too long for a novella. I don't remember the cover.
This novel takes place in and around one single building. It is a huge one, in length and width, and especially in height. Most people live inside, but adventurous people live outside, hanging on the walls. A lot of those belong to so-called "clans militaires" ("military clans") which are really just criminal gangs. This gives a "dystopia flavor" to the book. But there are also a few individuals who try to eke a subsistence there. The POV character is one of those. IIRC, he is a free-lance journalist, selling interesting videos to a news agency, whenever he can find a scoop.
There is another sentient species who lives outside, in the air. IIRC, humans call them in French "anges", that is "angels". They look very much like humans (they have only four limbs, no wings) but are no denser than air. They float around the building. They are definitely sentient, they have a few contacts with humans, but not much.
I don't remember much else, but I think the story is very complicated for such a rather shortish novel.

This is Farewell Horizontal by K.W. Jeter.
The story is set in a single gigantic structure. The main character is a freelance journalist/artist. There are numerous military clans. There are floating creatures called "gas angels" that appear to be humanoid but otherwise weightless.

You're either on the inside or the outside -- and either way, you're in trouble. A hustling young artist finds himself on the run from warring tribes, mysterious conspirators, body-swapping hackers and more, as he tries to both survive and strike it rich on the vertical surface of a skyscraper big enough to be its own world.


I don't often read novels anymore, but this sounds intriguing and metaphorical / allegorical.
